# Moving all files out from a directory and all its subdirectories

Tags: python-3.x

I have a small program that moves all files out of a directory and then searches all subdirectories for other files which it also moves out.

```
import shutil
import os
import ctypes   
import sys

copyfrom = r'D:\Downloads\'

copyto = r'D:\Downloads\'

for r, d, f in os.walk(copyfrom):
    for file in f:
        if os.path.join(r, file) == copyto:
            continue
        print(os.path.join(r, file))
        shutil.move(os.path.join(r, file), os.path.join(copyto, file))
```

It works right now but will overwrite every file that has a filename of an existing file. For example if i have banana.mp3 and banana.jpeg it will overwrite one of the files. Instead i would like the file with an existing name to be renamed.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add logic for getting a filename from your os.walk call with and without extensions.

Comment: Beside the point, but raw strings can't end in backslashes, so `r'D:\Downloads\'` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You may check whether the file exists using `os.path.exists(destination)` . But you should make sure that no race condition is going to happen. So you may open the existing file  using a command like `os.open()`, do your work and then close the file.

Comment: The problem is how i rename the file then? Does Shutil.move doesnt have an option on not to overrite the files but rename it when its allready there? I cant find anything on that.